# Class 'yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm' not found

Tags: php, yii2, bootstrapping

I am using a **Yii2** advanced app. The back end is fine, but I'm having a problem when I try to create a page (e.g., abc.php) in the front end/views folder, and then try to use a bootstrap ActiveForm class. For example:

```php
<?php

 use yii\helpers\Html;
 use bootstrap\ActiveForm;

?>

<div class="client-vehicle-info-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['layout' => 'horizontal']); ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Class 'bootstrap\ActiveForm' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\frontend\views\abc.php on line 10
```

Comment: try use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

Comment: I fixed the above error as under:                                              @import::using('yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm');
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;